# React Native - Navigating by ID from api with Redux not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

So, i'am using redux for my application and so far it's good. But recently I just hit a wall that stops me from coding for a while. I'am trying to make a navigation using the ID of every item in my database with redux. let's say I have a "category of food" page that is filled with item from my database and each of those items has their own ID, using those ID I'am trying to navigate to a second page which is the "dishes page". If a user clicks a category, the application should display the dishes that the category contains.

As of now, I manage to display the category but I don't know how to apply the navigation.

Whenever I try to add a kind of navigation that I know I'am facing an error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOyf0.png)

[state_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOq96.png) ( ** UPDATE ** )

You can see all the details in my code.

Here is my code:

App.js ( ** EDIT ** )

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import Reducer from './app/redux/reducers/Reducer';

import AppContainer from './app/container/AppContainer';
import DishContainer from './app/container/DishContainer';
import Dishes from './app/component/Dishes';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(Reducer);

export default class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store = { store }>
        <Root />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const Root = StackNavigator ({
  AppContainer        : { screen: AppContainer },
  DishContainer       : { screen: DishContainer },
  Dishes              : { screen: Dishes },
})
```

Action.js

```
import {
    FETCHING_CATEGORY_REQUEST,
    FETCHING_CATEGORY_SUCCESS,
    FETCHING_CATEGORY_FAILURE,

    FETCHING_DISHES_REQUEST,
    FETCHING_DISHES_SUCCESS,
    FETCHING_DISHES_FAILURE,
} from "./types";
import axios from 'axios';
/* ---------------------- CATEGORY ---------------------------- */
export const fetchingCategoryRequest = () => ({
    type: FETCHING_CATEGORY_REQUEST
});
export const fetchingCategorySuccess = (json) => ({
    type: FETCHING_CATEGORY_SUCCESS,
    payload: json,
});
export const fetchingCategoryFailure = (error) => ({
    type: FETCHING_CATEGORY_FAILURE,
    payload: error
});
export const fetchCategory = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get('http://192.168.254.100:3308/categories/')
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({ type: FETCHING_CATEGORY_SUCCESS, payload: response.data })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data));
    }
}
/* ---------------------- DISHES ---------------------------- */
export const fetchingDishesRequest = () => ({
    type: FETCHING_DISHES_REQUEST
});
export const fetchingDishesSuccess = (json) => ({
    type: FETCHING_DISHES_SUCCESS,
    dish: json,
});
export const fetchingDishesFailure = (error) => ({
    type: FETCHING_DISHES_FAILURE,
    dish: error,
});
export const fetchDish = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        axios.get('http://192.168.254.100:3308/categories/' + params.id)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({ type: FETCHING_DISHES_SUCCESS, dish: response.data })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data));
    }
}
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    isFetching: false,
    errorMessage: '',
    category: [],
    dishes: [],
};
const categoryReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCHING_CATEGORY_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: true
        };
        case FETCHING_CATEGORY_FAILURE:
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            errorMessage: action.payload
        };
        case FETCHING_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            category: action.payload
        };
/* --------------------- DISHES ------------------------- */
        case FETCHING_DISHES_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: true
        };
        case FETCHING_DISHES_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            dishes: action.dish
        };
        case FETCHING_DISHES_FAILURE:
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            errorMessage: action.dish
        }
        default:
        return state;
    }
}
export default categoryReducer;
```

CategoryList.js

```
export default class CategoryList extends Component {
    _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
      const { cat_name } = item;
        return (
            <View style={styles.cardContainerStyle}>
                <View style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style = { styles.buttonContainer }>
                        <Text style={styles.cardTextStyle}
                        onPress = { () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Dishes', { id: item.cat_id })}>
                            {cat_name}
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              data = {this.props.category}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

AppContainer.js

```
import CategoryList from "../component/CategoryList";
import { fetchCategory } from '../redux/actions/Actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AppContainer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchCategory();
    }
    render() {
        let content = <CategoryList category = { this.props.randomCategory.category }/>;
        if (this.props.randomCategory.isFetching) {
            content = <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>;
        }
        return <View style={styles.container}>{content}</View>;
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        randomCategory: state
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCategory })(AppContainer);
```

Dishes.js (This is where I want to navigate from Category)

```
export default class Dishes extends Component {
    _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
      const { cat_desc } = item;
        return (
            <View style={styles.cardContainerStyle}>
                <View style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.cardTextStyle}>
                            {cat_desc}
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    };
    render() {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        return (
            <FlatList
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              data = {this.props.dishes}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

DishContainer.js

```
import Dishes from "../component/Dishes";
import { fetchDish } from '../redux/actions/Actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class DishContainer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchDish();
    }
    render() {
        let content = <Dishes dishes = { this.props.randomDishes.dishes }/>;
        if (this.props.randomDishes.isFetching) {
            content = <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>;
        }
        return <View style={styles.container}>{content}</View>;
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        randomDishes: state
    };
}
```

EDIT: Some how the params is not working or the props.navigation.navigate is not calling the item's id from my api. I'am not sure, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your AppContainer.js like below :

```
import CategoryList from "../component/CategoryList";
import { fetchCategory } from '../redux/actions/Actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AppContainer extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCategory();
}
render() {
    let content = <CategoryList 
           navigation = {this.props.navigation}
           category = {this.props.randomCategory.category}/>;
    if (this.props.randomCategory.isFetching) {
        content = <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>;
    }
    return <View style={styles.container}>{content}</View>;
}
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    randomCategory: state
};
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCategory })(AppContainer);
```

The issue is `CategoryList` can't get `navigation` props of parent component(`AppCountainer`), So you have to pass `navigation` as props.

Comment: Thank you sir, you code remove the error. But, it doesn't navigate to the soconde screen.

Comment: Have you define `Dishes` in your navigation route?

Comment: I just define now the Dishes in my App.js. And it it is blank, why is that happening? I'll update my question for you to see my App.js

Comment: Which ReactNavigation version you used?

Comment: "react-native": "0.55.4", sir. Don't you think that this has something to do with my DishConainer, sir? Because I import my Dishes.js right there.

Comment: Try open `this.props.navigation.navigate('DishContainer')` then tell me DishContainer can open or not? and i ask for `react-navigation` version not for `react-native`.

Comment: It doesn't open, sir. And my emulator displays the same error again, I will update some screenshots. Also, my react-navigation is; "react-navigation": "^2.2.5"

Comment: Then use `createStackNavigator` instead of `StackNavigator`. See this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Comment: It didn't help sir, nothing is changed. Please, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: First check Text's onPress worked or not? Try console.log on OnPress.

Comment: Pass navigation props in Dish component like CategoryList

Comment: What do you mean by pass navigation props, sir? Instead, I copy paste the " navigation = {this.props.navigation} " in my DishContainer.js but it gives me the fisrt error that I encounter.